# What are the correct names of unit interpolations and how to implement them?

Tags: c#, .net, math, interpolation

I can't find for the life of me the correct names for interpolations like the ones below.

I am trying to look them up google using `ease-in interpolation`, `types of interpolation`, but without much luck.

All I want is to implement them in a fashion like this:

```
double Interp ( double value, double t )
```

where `value` is the value to be interpolated and `t` is the time value that can be any value between 0-1, including 0 and 1.

So if `Interp` was using a linear interpolation and `value` was 10, and `t` was 0.5, the return would be 5. But I want to get the values using other interpolations.

Any help on this?

I remember seeing a website with flash animations showing the formula of each one time but can't find it anymore.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've heard this referred to as "easing" or "tweening".

- http://robertpenner.com/easing/ has a Flash demo and links to a PDF file with the equations.
- http://code.google.com/p/tweener/ has an ActionScript library to implement them, with links to ports in JavaScript, Python, C++, etc.
- http://gsgd.co.uk/sandbox/jquery/easing/ is an easing plugin for jQuery.

Answer (score 1):

Interpolation involves estimating a curve based on a set of inputs, the larger the set of inputs the better the curve estimation. Is this what you are trying to do here? This guys talks about linear and quadratic interpolation techniques. http://www.codeproject.com/KB/recipes/simple_interpolation.aspx. If you want some more specialised interpolation techniques we really need to know a little more about the shape of the curve you are trying to estimate

Answer (score 0):

See: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Interpolation.html